# Modelling a Javascript object in Purescript

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, purescript

I'm trying to model in Purescript the [`SetOptions`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.SetOptions) data type from Firestore.

Up to now I have the following

```
foreign import data FieldPath :: Type

foreign import buildFieldPath :: Array String -> FieldPath

foreign import fieldNames :: FieldPath -> Array String

type MergeFields = Array (String \/ FieldPath)

data SetOptions
  = MergeOption Merge
  | MergeFieldsOption MergeFields
```

Note that `SetOptions` is a sum type since the `merge` and `mergeFields` are mutually exclusive (even if this is not documented).

Now I need to convert `SetOptions` into a Javascript object, so that I can pass it to some function from the Javascript `firebase` library.

It should be something of the form

```
{
  "mergeFields": [
    "foo",
    new FieldPath("bar", "baz")
  ]
}
```

My issue is the type of this.

I can't use [`Object`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-foreign-object/2.0.2/docs/Foreign.Object#t:Object) since the contained data are not homogeneous (`merge` refers to booleans, `mergeFields` refers to arrays).

I can't use [`Json`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-argonaut-core/5.0.2/docs/Data.Argonaut.Core#t:Json) because I need to have `FieldPath` objects in the result.

The only solution I found up to now is returning some `Json` and then on the javascript side parse it and add the `FieldPath` objects where needed, but it looks dirty and brittle.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation and examples for [purescript-variant](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-variant/5.2.0), which lets you define coproducts in terms of Purescript records. These are very nice for JS interop.

Comment: @marcosh I'm not sure if you are notified about my edits but I've added a link to additional resources at the end of my response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably skip coproduct `SetOption` representation on the PS side and just provide these two "dirty" constructors:

```
foreign import data SetOption :: Type

merge :: Boolean -> SetOption
merge m = unsafeCoerce { merge: m }

mergeFields :: MergeFields -> SetOption
mergeFields mf = unsafeCoerce { mergeFields: mf }
```

I would probably do the same for `MergeFields` coproduct.

We are doing something similar in our community project - material ui bindings: `purescript-react-basic-mui`. Additionally we are grouping these related constructors into records to achieve "cheap namespacing" because we are generating all these bindings from typescript declarations, but this is not really important in this context.
Please take a look at some definitions in this example module:

https://github.com/purescript-react-basic-mui/purescript-react-basic-mui/blob/codegen-read-dts/src/MUI/Core/Badge.purs#L20

EDIT: I think that [this latest discourse thread](https://discourse.purescript.org/t/how-to-create-a-javascript-object-with-a-value-that-doesnt-have-a-fixed-type/1233/) can be a good additional inspiration for you @macrosh.